# Вызов функции

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток! Почему так работает - `App['showNoty']()`,   
а так выдает ошибку -     `v.obj[v.method]()`?

Comment: Потому, что в квадратных скобках должно быть имя (строка), а не объект.

Comment: какую ошибку выдает ? у меня все работает: http://jsfiddle.net/kt7qt/

Comment: Может Вам эти фразы кажутся понятными, но другим нет, попытайтесь донести свои мысли более внятно(может даже примером завершенного кода). А вообще обращение к массиву грубо говоря эквивалентно обращению к свойству: object\["имя_метода"\]() = object.имя_метода()

Comment: Не подумал. Я имел ввиду это http://jsfiddle.net/yxudS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже указал, это можно сравнить с тем же, что поставить точку. Фактически вы обращаетесь к свойствам того же объекта, который стоит в начале. Но таких свойств у него просто нету.

```
App['showNoty']() приравнивается к App.showNoty();
v.obj[v.method]() приравнивается к v.obj.showNoty();
```

Соответственно v.obj - это строка 'App' и у строки никакого метода showNoty нет. Даже если вы напишете v[v.obj][v.method]() - это будет v.App.showNoty(), что тоже бессмысленно.

Смысл будет иметь к примеру такое построение(обращение к глобальной window): http://jsfiddle.net/TLsTz/

```
window[v.obj][v.method]() = window.App.ShowNote()
```

Ну и ссылка на описание сего безобразия:
http://learn.javascript.ru/object

Answer (score 1):

Итак, вы пишете следующий код:

```
var v = {
    'obj'        : 'App',
    'method'     : 'showNoty'
}

var App = {
    showNoty : function(){
        alert(1);
    }
}

//App['showNoty']();
v.obj[v.method]()
```

так вот откуда же по-вашему JavaScript должен знать, что под значением **'App'** (обратите внимание на апострофы) нужно понимать именно объект **App**, а не строку, что есть на самом деле? Замените объявление объекта **v** на следующее и поменяйте местами объявление **v** и **App**,  и у вас будет вызываться именно функция из объекта **App**:

```
var v = {
    'obj'        : App,
    'method'     : 'showNoty'
}
```

Comment: В данном случае получится, что v.obj = undefined.

Comment: @Alexey123 очевидно, вы правы. Я почему-то считал, что в JS переменная становится доступной, даже будучи объявленной в нижележащем коде